# Delphi FMX TMainMenu first menu item doesn't show in OSX, OK in WIndows

Tags: windows, macos, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle

I created a Multi-Device Application in Delphi Seattle and added a TMainMenu with MenuItem1 and MenuItem2 (nothing else). Building and running for OSX, only MenuItem2 shows. Building and running for Windows, both menu items show. I didn't treat the two menu items any differently. Both were just added and not customized in any way. Anyone else experience this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The top level items in a Mac menu bar typically look like this:

```
Apple/system menu ('About this Mac', 'System Preferences...', etc.)
Application menu ('About XXX', 'Services', 'Hide XXX', 'Hide Others',
  'Show All', 'Quit XXX')
File menu
Edit Menu
...
```

In FMX (excepting the very first version), the first top level item in a TMainMenu represents the application menu. As such, you need to add an item before File (or whatever is your current first item) that is only show on OS X; its sub-items should then include the usual items of a Mac application menu. To implement those items' behaviour, you can utilise standard actions (TFileHideApp, TFileHideAppOthers, TFileExit). Or, in more detail:

- If there isn't one already, add a TActionList component to the form
- Double click the action list to bring up the action list editor
- Click on the add button's dropdown arrow, and select New Standard Action...
- Select all of TFileHideApp, TFileHideAppOthers and TFileExit, and click OK
- Back on the form, open up the menu editor by double clicking on the TMainMenu component
- Add an item immediately before the first one that currently exists; in the Object Inspector, call it (say) mnuApp
- Add at least four child items to mnuApp; using the Object Inspector, assign the Action property of the first to FileHideApp1, the second to FileHideAppOthers, and the fourth to FileExit1; set the Text of the third to a hyphen (-) to make it a separator
- Close the menu editor
- If one doesn't already exist, create a OnCreate handler for the form by double clicking its entry in the Object Inspector
- Add to FormCreate a line to hide mnuApp if not running on OS X. Conversely, if you already have a menu item for File|Exit, this should be hidden if running on OS X since the functionality is now Quit under the application menu:

...

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  mnuApp.Visible := (TOSVersion.Platform = pfMacOS);
  itmExit.Visible := (TOSVersion.Platform <> pfMacOS);
end;
```

Comment: Chris, thanks! Could you please outline the steps I need to follow? Even with your clues, I can't find any information by searching the web.

Comment: I think I worked it out. The Mac application menu can be hidden in Windows and the menu item in WIndows that shows 'About XXX' etc can be hidden on the Mac as follows:
`{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  MenuItem1.Visible := False
{$ELSE $IFDEF MACOS}
    MenuItem3.Visible := False
{$ENDIF}`

Comment: I wasn't clear what exactly you were unclear about, so I've just added a step-by-step guide (I started it before your second comment) - in this I've used a runtime TOSVersion check, though using a compile-time IFDEF is valid as well. That said, and not that it really matters, but I think it's better to check for it being (or not being) OS X however, given the application menu is a Mac oddity rather than the lack of an application menu being a Windows oddity.

Comment: Chris, thanks so much. Your step-by-step solution worked very nicely.